# How can I call a method in another method in the same class?

Tags: php, class, methods

I wonder if it is possible to call a method from another method inside the same class?

For exemple this code, very simple have a method `method_foo()` which calls the method `a()`:

```
<?php

    class foo {

        function a() {
            return 3;
        }

        function method_foo() {
            echo a();
        }
    }

    $obj = new foo();
    $obj->method_foo();

?>
```

But when I call `method_foo()`, I'm receiving this error:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function a() in
>   /home/guest/public_html/... on line ... Call Stack
>   # Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0015  312032  {main}( )   ../index.html:0 2   0.0156  523056  foo->method_foo(
>    )  ../index.html:1667

Why do I get this error? Can I make this example work?

Comment: Use `$this->a()` instead of `a()`

Comment: You need to call like $this->a(); 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php documentation is your friend.

Comment: You need to use $this->a(), $this represent current class. so current class call function a.

Comment: just to clarify the language : a method *is* a function that is in a class.  Your question should be "can one method call another from within the same class"

Comment: [**RTFM**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) It's PHP OOP basics!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need yo use $this to access this method.

```
class foo {

    function a()
    {
        return 3;
    }

    function __construct()
    {

    }

    function method_foo()
    {
        echo $this->a();
    }
}

$obj = new foo();
$obj->method_foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call method a() inside function method_foo() like this :

```
echo $this->a(); //this will output 3
```

You can read more about this at : http://php.net/manual/en/ref.classobj.php .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$this` to call same class methods/variables

```
 function method_foo()
 {
    echo $this->a();
 }
```